# Python Tkinter canvas update

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update the color of a circle in Tkinter in python 2. I can make my circle but the color does not update in my task() method until I stop running the program. How can I make the color update as soon as `val` is greater than 4?

```
from Tkinter import *
m = Tk()
w = Canvas(m, width = 100, height = 100)
w.pack()
cir = w.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100)

def task():
    while True:
        val += 1
        if val > 4:
            w.itemconfig(cir, fill = "blue")

m.after(2000, task)
m.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a `while True:` with no `break`. What did you expect?

Comment: I wrote the code wrong the first time but even with this fix it still doesnt update color

Comment: You still have a `while True:` with no `break`. Again, what did you expect?

Comment: @Brosten Please don't ninja-edit your question -- by adding indentation after people were already helping, you changed the code and rendered existing feedback redundant at best, and confusing at worst.

Comment: Given the code change, I'm removing my answer. Note that the problem lies in what @TigerhawkT3 identified in comments on that answer -- namely, you're hogging an entire CPU core to increment `val` as fast as it can, basically freezing your program unless you go into multiprocessing/threading. What you're trying to ask is how to refresh the display between each `while True` cycle.

Comment: I should also mention that I've been assuming that `val` is assigned somewhere in your code before you try to add 1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

Like @TigerhawkT3 said you need a break to exit the loop.

```
from Tkinter import *
m = Tk()
w = Canvas(m, width = 100, height = 100)
w.pack()
cir = w.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100)

def task():
    val = 1
    while True:
        val += 1
        if val > 4:
            w.itemconfig(cir, fill = "blue")

            #without the break task will run forever
            break

m.after(2000, task)
m.mainloop()
```

Comment: The OP commented in a now-deleted answer that he wants to keep incrementing `val` even after changing the fill color (didn't explain why, though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to do it the long way, and the only way.
Code:

```
from tkinter import *

m = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
c.pack()

v = 4

if v == 4:
    v = 0
    c.pack_forget()
    del c

    c = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg='blue')
    c.pack()

c.mainloop()
```

Do all the changing with v (I haven't put that in though)!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Wait, I didn't mean v, I meant val, sorry!